# How to install and configure apache flume?

Tags: flume

Am new in the Apache Flume. I need to install the flume on top of the HDFS cluster environment. I did Google it, all are saying using the cloudera distribution but I need to install and configure from the source.

So can anyone please suggest me, where to start and how to customize the flume agent and sink services?

Answer (score 4):

I have just installed Apache Flume 1.3 on Ubuntu.

You need to download the binary zip for your OS, extract it and create a config file which is similar to  properties file in Java.

The installation and running of agents is a dumb/easy process, just read [this](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#setup)

Answer (score 2):

installation steps

```
#step1
goto http://flume.apache.org/download.html

#click following link
apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz
```

http://apache.mesi.com.ar/flume/1.4.0/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz

```
#Download apache-flume by double clicking on the above link

tar -xvzf   apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz
mv apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz flume
chown -R hduser:hadoop flume

#go to flume conf  path

../../flume/conf
vi  flume-env.sh.template

#mention  JAVA Path
#mantion flume Classpath
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example tutorial that I've put together that uses flume, apache, flask and kibana in a vagrant environment.

There is a video at the bottom to give a better intro:

https://github.com/mross462/Flume-Elasticsearch

Comment: Answers that are little more than links are discourage here. Over the long term, links inevitably break, and your answer will then be useless. Consider expanding your answer to at least contain a brief summary of the content you link to, so that it may help people even if the link disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In the course **Moving Data into Hadoop** offered by **Big Data University** at :http://bigdatauniversity.com/bdu-wp/bdu-course/moving-data-into-hadoop/ teaches you intro to flume and a lab exercise which helps you with both configuring and running flume.

Answer (score 0):

FOR CENT OS

*step1 Download

```
[https://downloads.apache.org/flume/1.9.0/apache-flume-1.9.0-bin.tar.gz][1]
```

*Install apache flume
"tar -xvf  apache-flume-1.9.0-bin.tar.gz"

*Moving
"mv apache-flume-1.9.0-bin.tar.gz usr/local/flume"

*Setting path
"vim /etc/profile"

"export FLUME_HOME=/usr/local/flume
export PATH=$PATH:$FLUME_HOME/bin"

*Version
"flume-ng version"

*Conf
"usr/local/flume/conf"
in flume-conf.properties
set your hadoop properties